# SQL Aggregate Key and getting Primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am looking to get the primary key from a group by.

What i am looking for is to select all the Maximum and Minimum temperature for a day and get the primary key for that entry.

```
select Cast(DateTime as date) AS 'Date', MAX(Temperature) AS 'Max Temperature'
from [Testing].[dbo].[Reading]
GROUP by Cast(DateTime as date)
ORDER by Cast(DateTime as date)
```

This will find me the maximum temperature for each day however due to the group by i am unable to get the primary key for that entry that is the highest for that day. 
Any Help?

Comment: What if there are more readings with the same temperature? Dublicate? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: For this case all i care about it the maximum temperature on a day, if that happened once or twice does not matter

Comment: OK so if there are duplicates which one do you want?

Comment: The first occurrence, this will be used to display temperature by day so it does not matter the actual time the reading happened.

Comment: Then why do you need the key? You already have the temperature and day.

Comment: What is the Primary Key of the table?    Do you seriously have a column named "DateTime"?

Comment: I need the primary key so that i can then obtain the foreign key in the same row.
Since i will have many similar readings from different foreign keys
Primary key is ReadingId, and yes i do have a column named DateTime, i am planning to changing it i am just going through some very early development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Gordon answer:

```
select Cast(DateTime as date) AS [Date], Temperature AS MaxTemperature,     id_temperature
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Cast(DateTime as date)
                                order by DateTime desc, Temperature desc) as seqnum
      from [Testing].[dbo].[Reading] r
     ) r
order by Cast(DateTime as date);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select Cast(DateTime as date) AS [Date], MAX(Temperature) AS MaxTemperature,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then temperature end) as LastTemperature
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Cast(DateTime as date)
                                order by DateTime desc) as seqnum
      from [Testing].[dbo].[Reading] r
     ) r
group by Cast(DateTime as date)
order by Cast(DateTime as date);
```

EDIT:

If you want other values from the row with the maximum temperature, then you would use:

```
select Cast(DateTime as date) AS [Date], MAX(Temperature) AS MaxTemperature,
       max(case when seqnum_max = 1 then <whatever column here> end) as <whatever column>
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Cast(DateTime as date)
                                order by Temperature desc) as seqnum_max
      from [Testing].[dbo].[Reading] r
     ) r
group by Cast(DateTime as date)
order by Cast(DateTime as date);
```

You would use another variable for the minimum.

Comment: This does not give me the primary key from which the maximum temperature comes from

Comment: Its good, just change ```MAX(Temperature) AS MaxTemperature``` by ```Temperature AS MaxTemperature``` and change ```order by DateTime desc``` in the partition by ```order by DateTime desc, Temperature desc``` and remove the group by